# Formatting Column in RADGRID

Tags: datatable, radgrid, dataformat

I am binding a datatable having a column with values like www.google.com,www.google.com.
But I like to render only one www.google.com in RADGrid.How can I achieve it with data format string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write your own custom FormatProvider to do something like this.

This is a simple example:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/custom-iformatprovider/